# pollEnrich from FTP

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I'm trying enrich using dynamically selected remote files on an FTP server using pollEnrich. The remote files must remain in place and can be selected again and again so the endpoint has noop=true and idempotent=false. Everything seems to work fine until multiple requests start coming in that use the same remote file for enrichment, and this results in all but a few of the requests receiving a null body for the new exchange argument in the aggregation strategy. Here is the relevant part of the route, which has been modified slightly to post here:

```
.pollEnrich()
  .simple("ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/path/files?fileName=${header.sourceFilename}&passiveMode=true&noop=true&idempotent=false")
  .timeout(0)
  .cacheSize(-1)
  .aggregationStrategy(myEnrichmentAggregationStrategy)
```

I switched to using file:// instead of ftp:// as a test and still experienced the same problems. I also tried different modes for timeout, cacheSize, and also enabling streamCaching since the body is an InputStream. I'm now thinking about implementing a custom read-lock mechanism (processStrategy) but it feels like a long shot workaround. Has anyone else come across this problem and can shed some light on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found a solution and it is using the `inProgressRepository` property on the polling consumer to set a dummy implementation of `IdempotentRepository`, allowing me to disable the check for in progress files.